# Best way to download and build a package dependency?

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lets say I want my new project to depend on 'freenect'. What would the best way to download and install that package be? Is there an automated tool that works?

I tried this:

$ rosdep install freenect

Warning: could not identify ['freenect'] as a package

rosdep: error: No Valid Packages listed

And this:

$ rosmake freenect --rosdep-install

[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['freenect']

And lastly this:

/src/robos/ros-workspace$ rosinstall . https://github.com/ros-pkg-git/kinect/raw/master/kinect.rosinstall

ERROR: No 'ros' stack detected.  The 'ros' stack is required in all rosinstall directories. Please add a definition of the 'ros' stack either manually in .rosinstall and then call 'rosinstall .' in the directory. Or add one on the command line 'rosinstall . [http://www.ros.org/rosinstalls/boxturtle_ros.rosinstall'](http://www.ros.org/rosinstalls/boxturtle_ros.rosinstall%27). Or reference an existing install like in /opt/ros/boxturtle with 'rosinstall . /opt/ros/boxturtle'.  Note: the above suggestions assume you are using boxturtle, if you are using latest or another distro please change the urls.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9187/best-way-to-download-and-build-a-package-dependency?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-02-24**:
Obviously, I could follow the hint in the rosinstall output, but I'm not sure if i'm barking up the wrong tree with it - I didn't see any mention of rosinstall in the tutorial and I just stumbled on it's existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are instructions for installing the Kinect on the wiki at http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect

In general you will need to either have a fully encompassing rosinstall file which includes all dependencies or you need to overlay it on top of an existing ros installation.  If you install the dependencies from debian packages for cturtle you would call:

```
rosinstall . /opt/ros/cturtle kinect.rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-02-24**:
Alright :) seems that rosinstall is the way to go. I think I was just confused a bit by having three 'install' options.